# Where can I find the 4.3 Camera app with Photosphere?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-4, google-apps

I just updated Cyanogenmod 10.1 to 10.2 (nightly) and noticed that the Camera app (not Focal) no longer has the ability to take Photospheres. I'm guessing it's related to [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1kbeoh/gapps_20130813_for_android_43_and_20130812_for/cbn9lb9). How can I get the "regular" Camera app for Android 4.3 on my Nexus 4?

Comment: It looks like the default camera app is not compatible. You will have to download a 3rd party Camera app off of the Play Store. Here is a good list: [12 Best Android Camera Apps](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19736_7-57429313-251/the-12-best-android-camera-apps-around/). If you are into open-source software and whatnot, you can start a [Git repository](https://github.com) for it and see if anyone will help you with it.

Comment: @John Why isn't the regular Camera app compatible? I could understand if I had some other device but the regular Camera app is designed to work with the Nexus 4. I've already flashed the 4.3 GApps package so I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Its possible the camera relied on some core function of the stock os, which must have not transferred over to the ROM. I'm not really sure why it's not compatible, you could post a new thread on the cyanogen forum if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [upgrading to 10.2 from 10.1 page](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/74526-how-do-i-update-cyanogenmod/#entry402538) links to a flashable zip with the Photosphere enabled Camera app. That link appears to currently be broken. [Here](http://goo.im/devs/BaNkS/GApps%204.3/8-18_Photosphere_Camera_4.3.zip) is a working link. After flashing, the Camera app has the ability to take Photospheres.